# Straighten contours OpenCV

Tags: opencv, python

Hello guys I would like to "straighten" some contours using opencv/python. Is there anyway to accomplish this?
I have attached two images:

1. in the current stage [image: 1]
2. and how I would like to see it [image: 2].

Bounding boxes resolve the majority of the problem, but there are some exceptions that do not produce the desired outcome (see the top right contour in the image).
Thank you very much!

[Current Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqdf4.png)

[Squared Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5966D.png)

Comment: How are you doing it right now? Did you try to to use [find_countours](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) and then [bounding_rect](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7)? [Here an example](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: I tried bounding box but it works only for convex forms. and afterwards I tried to go into each contour and for each 3 points I calculated the angle and if it is in a certain range I made it either 90 or 180 degrees.

Comment: ok, now I see your point. But I don't get how you decide when you want just a rectangle and when you want a different shape. If you can formulate that, it will help. Let me explain: the top-left shape also could be "bounded" the same way as the top-right, but (I guess) since the black space is small, you do not want it. But you most likely won't find an operator that does that, because they are two different way to deal with the same problem. I think you could break the task into creating bounding boxes and dividing them when the black area is larger than a certain percentage (for example).

Comment: Yes you're right, is hard to find a way to describe whether the resulting contour should be a bounding box or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
def approximate_contours(image: np.ndarray, eps: float, color=(255, 255, 255)):
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(image, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    approx_contours = []
    for cnt in contours:
        epsilon = eps * cv.arcLength(cnt, True)
        approx = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)
        cv.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, color=color)

        approx_contours.append(approx)

    return image, approx_contours


def get_angle(pts: np.ndarray):
    a = np.array([pts[0][0][0], pts[0][0][1]])
    b = np.array([pts[1][0][0], pts[1][0][1]])
    c = np.array([pts[2][0][0], pts[2][0][1]])
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b
    unit_vector_ba = ba / np.linalg.norm(ba)
    unit_vector_bc = bc / np.linalg.norm(bc)
    dot_product = np.dot(unit_vector_ba, unit_vector_bc)
    angle_rad = np.arccos(dot_product)
    angle_deg = degrees(angle_rad)

    try:
        int(angle_deg)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("nan value detected")

    return int(angle_deg)


def move_points(contour:np.ndarray, pts: np.ndarray, angle: int, ext: list, weight=1):
    (ext_left, ext_right, ext_bot, ext_top) = ext
    a = np.array([pts[0][0][0], pts[0][0][1]])
    b = np.array([pts[1][0][0], pts[1][0][1]])
    c = np.array([pts[2][0][0], pts[2][0][1]])

    right_angle = False
    if 45 < angle < 135:
        right_angle = True
        diff_x_ba = abs(b[0] - a[0])
        diff_y_ba = abs(b[1] - a[1])
        diff_x_bc = abs(b[0] - c[0])
        diff_y_bc = abs(b[1] - c[1])
        rap_ba = diff_x_ba / max(diff_y_ba, 1)
        rap_bc = diff_x_bc / max(diff_y_bc, 1)

        if rap_ba < rap_bc:
            a[0] = int((a[0] * weight + b[0]) / (2 + weight - 1))
            b[0] = a[0]
            c[1] = int((c[1] + b[1]) / 2)
            b[1] = c[1]
        else:
            c[0] = int((c[0] + b[0]) / 2)
            b[0] = c[0]
            a[1] = int((a[1] * weight + b[1]) / (2 + weight - 1))
            b[1] = a[1]
    else:
        diff_x_ba = abs(b[0] - a[0])
        diff_y_ba = abs(b[1] - a[1])
        diff_x_bc = abs(b[0] - c[0])
        diff_y_bc = abs(b[1] - c[1])
        if (diff_x_ba + diff_x_bc) > (diff_y_ba + diff_y_bc):
            a[1] = int((a[1] * weight + b[1] + c[1]) / (3 + weight - 1))

            b[1] = a[1]
            c[1] = a[1]
        else:
            a[0] = int((a[0] * weight + b[0] + c[0]) / (3 + weight - 1))

            b[0] = a[0]
            c[0] = a[0]

    return a, b, c, right_angle


def straighten_contours(contours: list, image: np.ndarray, color=(255, 255, 255)):
    image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for cnt in contours:
        idx = 0
        ext_left = cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmin()][0]
        ext_right = cnt[cnt[:, :, 0].argmax()][0]
        ext_top = cnt[cnt[:, :, 1].argmin()][0]
        ext_bot = cnt[cnt[:, :, 1].argmax()][0]

        while idx != int(cnt.size / 2):
            try:
                angle = get_angle(cnt[idx:idx + 3])
            except Exception:
                idx += 1
                continue
            (a, b, c, right_angle) = move_points(cnt, cnt[idx:idx + 3], angle, [ext_left, ext_right, ext_bot, ext_top])
            cnt[idx][0] = a
            cnt[idx + 1][0] = b
            cnt[idx + 2][0] = c
            idx += 1
            if not right_angle:
                idx -= 1
                cnt = np.delete(cnt, (idx + 1), 0)

            if idx == 1:
                cnt = np.append(cnt, cnt[:2], axis=0)

        cnt = np.delete(cnt, [0, 1], 0)
        cv.drawContours(image, [cnt], -1, color=color)

    return image
```

I managed to do some workarounds. The straighten contours function is applied onto the approximate_contours result (the first image in the question). Is not as good as I would have wanted it to be but it works.

[image: Result]